# Need help saving developer tools log

Tags: javascript, firefox, interface, save, environment

I opened a developer tools in the middle of running JS and found behavior is I to save for in depth analysis. Is there any way I can save the complete information in all of the developer tools screen?

Comment: Can you tell exactly what information you want to save the timeline tab or the application tab info or the profiler info?

Comment: I would like to save all information. There is too much that I need. I guess the JS functions and network data are most relevant now.

Comment: Sorry. I did not specify. This is in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're talking about **Chrome Dev Tolls**, if you want to save the information in the Console, just right click any blank space in the Console an choose 'Save As'.

If you need to save the information in the Performance section, there's a Save Profile button (with an arrow down icon) in the top, you can save a JSON with all the information.

And there's another cool way you can debbug your Javascript code with Chrome Dev Tools: you can stablish *breakpoints* in your code. This article [here](https://codeburst.io/learn-how-to-debug-javascript-with-chrome-devtools-9514c58479db) explain how you can do it with an nice example.